# babel extract html does't work

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, python-babel

```
<div>
    <table class="table" ng-hide="collapsed || filesVM.files.length == 0">
        <tr>
            <th>{{_('Filename')}}
                <small class="text-muted">({{ (filesVM.files | filter:fileSearch).length }} files)</small>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

babel doesn't work, it cant extract the content, but it can work as below

```
<div>
    <table class="table" ng-hide="collapsed || filesVM.files.length == 0">
        <tr>
            <th>{{_('Filename')}}
                <small class="text-muted"></small>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

with config

```
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
encoding = utf-8
extensions = jinja2.ext.autoescape, jinja2.ext.with_
```

how to change to make it work, and I'm not familiar with this field. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use tag gettext `{{ gettext('your text') }}` or maybe you forgot to set Jinja:

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = {
    'extensions': [
        'jinja2.ext.i18n'
   ]
}
```